# Which is the minimum width at which default layout is used

Tags: android, layout

I am creating alternative layouts for my activities, for example sw320dp, etc. I plan to create another for sw480dp, and sw600dp, sw720dp.
In which segment falls the default layout, the one without qualifiers? So I don't duplicate code.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: The default layout is set when it does not meet any requirements

Answer (score 0):

you can use a -nodpi qualifier to set the generics layouts.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally acceptable to create sw320dp,sw480dp,sw600dp and sw720dp.
You don't need to think about the smallest width since it will choose on its own depends on the device size.
So just create those layouts 320-720 and if the device is not in those sizes it will just fall into the default one.